# return query into stringbuilder

Tags: asp.net, stringbuilder

im just trying to return a query into stringbuilder in order to generate dinamicly html

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page              
    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function BuscarTurbos(referencia As String) As String
        Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
        Dim conexion As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=PC-TOSH\misql ;Initial Catalog=Rotomaster;Integrated Security=True")
        conexion.Open()
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT VehicleModel,Year FROM TURBOSNUEVO WHERE TurboModel like '%" + referencia + "%'", conexion)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If dr.HasRows Then
            While dr.Read
                sb.Append("<p style='background-color:red;width:50%;height:100px'>'" + dr("VehicleModel").ToString(), CType(dr("Year"), Double) + "' </p>")
            End While
        End If    
        Return sb.ToString    
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: What is your question? What is not working? I would also suggest using AppendFormat on the stringbuilder.

Comment: when i run it, i got this _:::::La conversión de la cadena "' </p>" en el tipo 'Double' no es válida.

Comment: it means i cant convert </p> in Double

Comment: Looks like it might be an issue with the ctype into double. Just add .ToString() after like this: **CType(dr("Year"), Double).ToString()**

Answer (score 0):

I would change your

```
sb.Append("<p style='background-color:red;width:50%;height:100px'>'" + dr("VehicleModel").ToString(), CType(dr("Year"), Double) + "' </p>")
```

into this:

```
sb.AppendFormat("<p style='background-color:red;width:50%;height:100px'>{0} {1}</p>", dr("VehicleModel").ToString(), dr("Year").ToString())
```

One note about string concatenating (joining together) - strings are immutible meaning each time you join strings together, it has to create a new string object since they cannot be changed. By using AppendFormat, it saves you from having to create extra string objects.

Comment: great. I also added some info about why I changed your code to use AppendFormat.